# Can I use a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow to change multiple explicit permissions on a document from contribute to read only?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I am trying to create a workflow that will check through all the permissions on a document in a library (including extra explicit permissions) and change them from contribute to read only.

I'm quite new to the whole thing. So I'm just wondering if it's possible? If it is, could someone point me in the right direction please?

What I'm using: SharePoint Online, SharePoint Designer 2013, 2013 Workflow.

Thank you!

Edit: To clarify I'm using a 2013 workflow already that I need to insert this in to. When trying to select users, in most cases I wont know exactly who the users are and some may be external.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer workflow you can choose `Replace List Item Permissions` action.

Then choose the list of users and select View permission.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Amal. To clarify I'm using a 2013 workflow already that I need to insert this in to (I believe the action you mentioned is 2010). Also, when you mention selecting the users, in most cases I wont know exactly who the users are and some may be external.